# Indirect formula to increment cell the cell AND the column?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a worksheet name in cell C11 which I am referencing in a formula with a `=INDIRECT` formula.

I have also added the `=ROW` formula so that it increments the row number when I drag it down my worksheet.

My formula looks like this: `=INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!C"&ROW(C12))`

How can I modify it so it also increments the column when I drag it right?

I've tried to use the `=column` method, but I assume I am doing something wrong as I just get a reference error, can anybody assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column() returns the Column number, so you may use the R1C1 variant of INDIRECT.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!R"&ROW(C12)&"C"&COLUMN(C12),FALSE)
```

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

A bit long, but working. Assume A2 has the =Column(A1) formula for the whole row.

Isert into A3 and copy to the while row:

```
=IF(A2>26,CHAR(64+ROUNDDOWN((A2+1)/26,0))&CHAR(64+A2-26*ROUNDDOWN((A2+1)/26,0)),CHAR(64+A2-26*ROUNDDOWN((A2-1)/26,0)))
```

This works only for the one and two letter columns. You can expand if you need after ZZ column.